# How to change the direction of photos?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating a sample website for a bakery and I have three clickable photos that will lead to other pages on the site. They are all currently sitting on top of each other and I would like for them to be next to each other. I'm pretty new to coding and this is also my first post on stack overflow so let me know if I need to clarify anything or post more code. Thanks so much for any help.

I've tried `img {flex-direction: row}`, and tried wrapping all of my images inside of a div and changing the flex-direction like that.

```css
img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  border: solid white 3px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514432324607-a09d9b4aefdd? 
    ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60" alt="cup of coffee">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 featured-gallery">
  <div class="col-sm-12 thumbnail text-center">
    <img alt="regional park A" class="img-responsive" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530019163123-f33edadb3833? 
     ixlib=rb- 
     1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 featured-gallery">
  <div class="col-sm-12 thumbnail text-center">
    <img alt="regional park B" class="img-responsive" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509365465985-25d11c17e812? 
    ixlib=rb- 
    1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80">
  </div>
</div>
```

My expected results are my photos laying next to each other in a row but my actual results are my photos laying next to each other in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were targeting flexbox layout on the image element itself which did not have any child element to process the direction. By default the columns had [**`block`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Block_and_Inline_Layout_in_Normal_Flow) level behavior which takes up the whole row. Wrap the images inside a parent container and then adjust the markup like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  border: solid white 3px;
  transition: transform .2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 featured-gallery">
    <div class="col-sm-12 thumbnail text-center">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514432324607-a09d9b4aefdd? 
    ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60" alt="cup of coffee">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 featured-gallery">
    <div class="col-sm-12 thumbnail text-center">
      <img alt="regional park A" class="img-responsive" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530019163123-f33edadb3833? 
     ixlib=rb- 
     1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 featured-gallery">
    <div class="col-sm-12 thumbnail text-center">
      <img alt="regional park B" class="img-responsive" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509365465985-25d11c17e812? 
    ixlib=rb- 
    1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80">
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so so much! This fixed my problem :) I've since learned that I need to be putting parent containers around my flex items so hopefully that'll help me avoid this next time. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :) I think you did not mention the library that you are using. If it is Bootstrap then don't forget to use these guidelines: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Youre close! What you need is a parent element that wraps around all the images and is a flexbox. Then, you give each img a flex property so the flexbox parent knows how to scale and size them.

You can check out a good article about how to set up a flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Flexbox may also be overkill for this too, you can set them to have display:inline and they will be side by side. You can read more about inline vs block elements here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Comment: Oh okay, so when working with flexbox there always needs to be a parent container? Thanks you so much- I'll take a look at those articles when I get some time tonight!

Comment: Yup! Think of it as the children are "in" the flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this rule :

```css
    img
    {
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Bootstrap's grid system. Your current design snippet works but is not technically correct and you could experience some issues as you move forward.

To ensure the layout works correction it should be 
.container
  .row
     .col

This would become important as you add more rows of content on the page. 
You can review the general layout on Bootstraps documentation pages. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Place a "row" div around your image divs